# Implementation of the Discrete Fourier Transform - FFT

Tags: c++, signal-processing, dft

I am trying to do a project in sound processing and need to put the frequencies into another domain. Now, I have tried to implement an FFT, that didn't go well. I tried to understand the `z`-transform, that didn't go to well either. I read up and found DFT's a lot more simple to understand, especially the algorithm. So I coded the algorithm using examples but I do not know or think the output is right. (I don't have Matlab on here, and cannot find any resources to test it) and wondered if you guys knew if I was going in the right direction. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const double PI = 3.141592;

vector< complex<double> > DFT(vector< complex<double> >& theData)
{
// Define the Size of the read in vector
const int S = theData.size();

// Initalise new vector with size of S
vector< complex<double> > out(S, 0);
for(unsigned i=0; (i < S); i++)
{
    out[i] = complex<double>(0.0, 0.0);
    for(unsigned j=0; (j < S); j++)
    {
        out[i] += theData[j] * polar<double>(1.0, - 2 * PI * i * j / S);
    }
}

return out;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

vector< complex<double> > numbers;

numbers.push_back(102023);
numbers.push_back(102023);
numbers.push_back(102023);
numbers.push_back(102023);

vector< complex<double> > testing = DFT(numbers);

for(unsigned i=0; (i < testing.size()); i++)
{
    cout << testing[i] << endl;

}
}
```

The inputs are:

```
102023               102023

102023               102023
```

And the result:

```
(408092,       0)

(-0.0666812,  -0.0666812)

(1.30764e-07, -0.133362)

(0.200044,    -0.200043)
```

Any help or advice would be great, I'm not expecting a lot, but, anything would be great. Thank you :)

Comment: Why don't you use the ever popular FFTW library? http://www.fftw.org/

Comment: Thank's for your reply, I'm not allowed to use libraries.

Comment: The only problem I can see is that you're losing a lot of accuracy by only specifying `PI` to 7 figures. (Ignoring performance of course; for a large input, this will be enormously slower than the equivalent FFT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks okey. `out[0]` should represent the "DC" component of your input waveform. In your case, it is 4 times bigger than the input waveform, because your normalization coefficient is 1.

The other coefficients should represent the amplitude and phase of your input waveform. The coefficients are mirrored, i.e., out[i] == out[N-i]. You can test this with the following code:

```
double frequency = 1; /* use other values like 2, 3, 4 etc. */
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    numbers.push_back(sin((double)i / 16 * frequency * 2 * PI));
```

For `frequency = 1`, this gives:

```
(6.53592e-07,0)
(6.53592e-07,-8)
(6.53592e-07,1.75661e-07)
(6.53591e-07,2.70728e-07)
(6.5359e-07,3.75466e-07)
(6.5359e-07,4.95006e-07)
(6.53588e-07,6.36767e-07)
(6.53587e-07,8.12183e-07)
(6.53584e-07,1.04006e-06)
(6.53581e-07,1.35364e-06)
(6.53576e-07,1.81691e-06)
(6.53568e-07,2.56792e-06)
(6.53553e-07,3.95615e-06)
(6.53519e-07,7.1238e-06)
(6.53402e-07,1.82855e-05)
(-8.30058e-05,7.99999)
```

which seems correct to me: negligible DC, amplitude 8 for 1st harmonics, negligible amplitudes for other harmonics.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It can't be THIS simple though, can it? The maths look really complicated.. It's weird!

Comment: @Phorce: Yes, the DFT really is this simple. Optimising it to the FFT is rather more complicated, though.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I've noticed the FFT is more complex. One thing that's confusing me now is.. I'm given the output (num,num) but how do I perform calculations on these numbers? I have a lot more to do!

Comment: "How do I perform calculations on these numbers?" is very ambiguous. Try to refine your question.

Answer (score 6):

@Phorce is right here. I don't think there is any reson to reinvent the wheel. However, if you want to do this so that you understand the methodology *and* to have the joy of coding it yourself I can provide a FORTRAN FFT code that I developed some years ago. Of course this is not C++ and will require a translation; this should not be too difficult and should enable you to learn a lot in doing so...

Below is a Radix 4 based algorithm; this radix-4 FFT recursively partitions a DFT into four quarter-length DFTs of groups of every fourth time sample. The outputs of these shorter FFTs are reused to compute many outputs, thus greatly reducing the total computational cost. The radix-4 decimation-in-frequency FFT groups every fourth output sample into shorter-length DFTs to save computations. The radix-4 FFTs require only 75% as many complex multiplies as the radix-2 FFTs. See [here](http://cnx.org/content/m12027/latest/) for more information.

```
!+ FILE: RADIX4.FOR
! ===================================================================
! Discription: Radix 4 is a descreet complex Fourier transform algorithim. It 
! is to be supplied with two real arrays, one for real parts of function
! one for imaginary parts: It can also unscramble transformed arrays.
! Usage: calling FASTF(XREAL,XIMAG,ISIZE,ITYPE,IFAULT); we supply the 
! following: 
!
! XREAL - array containing real parts of transform sequence    
! XIMAG - array containing imagianry parts of transformation sequence
! ISIZE - size of transform (ISIZE = 4*2*M)
! ITYPE - +1 forward transform
!         -1 reverse transform
! IFAULT - 1 if error
!        - 0 otherwise
! ===================================================================
!
! Forward transform computes:
!     X(k) = sum_{j=0}^{isize-1} x(j)*exp(-2ijk*pi/isize)
! Backward computes:
!     x(j) = (1/isize) sum_{k=0}^{isize-1} X(k)*exp(ijk*pi/isize)
!
! Forward followed by backwards will result in the origonal sequence!
!
! ===================================================================

      SUBROUTINE FASTF(XREAL,XIMAG,ISIZE,ITYPE,IFAULT)

      REAL*8 XREAL(*),XIMAG(*)
      INTEGER MAX2,II,IPOW

      PARAMETER (MAX2 = 20)

! Check for valid transform size upto 2**(max2):
      IFAULT = 1
      IF(ISIZE.LT.4) THEN
         print*,'FFT: Error: Data array < 4 - Too small!'
         return
      ENDIF
      II = 4
      IPOW = 2 

! Prepare mod 2:
 1    IF((II-ISIZE).NE.0) THEN 
         II = II*2
         IPOW = IPOW + 1       
         IF(IPOW.GT.MAX2) THEN
            print*,'FFT: Error: FFT1!'
            return
         ENDIF
         GOTO 1
      ENDIF

! Check for correct type:
      IF(IABS(ITYPE).NE.1) THEN
         print*,'FFT: Error: Wrong type of transformation!'
         return
      ENDIF

! No entry errors - continue:
      IFAULT = 0

! call FASTG to preform transformation:
      CALL FASTG(XREAL,XIMAG,ISIZE,ITYPE)

! Due to Radix 4 factorisation results are not in the same order
! after transformation as they were when the data was submitted:
! We now call SCRAM, to unscramble the reults:

      CALL SCRAM(XREAL,XIMAG,ISIZE,IPOW)

      return

      END

!-END: RADIX4.FOR


! ===============================================================
! Discription: This is the radix 4 complex descreet fast Fourier
! transform with out unscrabling. Suitable for convolutions or other
! applications that do not require unscrambling. Designed for use 
! with FASTF.FOR.
!
      SUBROUTINE FASTG(XREAL,XIMAG,N,ITYPE)

      INTEGER N,IFACA,IFCAB,LITLA
      INTEGER I0,I1,I2,I3

      REAL*8 XREAL(*),XIMAG(*),BCOS,BSIN,CW1,CW2,PI
      REAL*8 SW1,SW2,SW3,TEMPR,X1,X2,X3,XS0,XS1,XS2,XS3
      REAL*8 Y1,Y2,Y3,YS0,YS1,YS2,YS3,Z,ZATAN,ZFLOAT,ZSIN

      ZATAN(Z) = ATAN(Z)
      ZFLOAT(K) = FLOAT(K) ! Real equivalent of K.
      ZSIN(Z) = SIN(Z)

      PI = (4.0)*ZATAN(1.0)
      IFACA = N/4

! Forward transform:
      IF(ITYPE.GT.0) THEN
         GOTO 5
      ENDIF

! If this is for an inverse transform - conjugate the data:
      DO 4, K = 1,N
         XIMAG(K) = -XIMAG(K)
 4    CONTINUE

 5    IFCAB = IFACA*4

! Proform appropriate transformations:
      Z = PI/ZFLOAT(IFCAB)
      BCOS = -2.0*ZSIN(Z)**2
      BSIN = ZSIN(2.0*Z)
      CW1 = 1.0
      SW1 = 0.0

! This is the main body of radix 4 calculations:
      DO 10, LITLA = 1,IFACA
         DO 8, I0 = LITLA,N,IFCAB

            I1 = I0 + IFACA
            I2 = I1 + IFACA
            I3 = I2 + IFACA
            XS0 = XREAL(I0) + XREAL(I2)
            XS1 = XREAL(I0) - XREAL(I2)
            YS0 = XIMAG(I0) + XIMAG(I2)
            YS1 = XIMAG(I0) - XIMAG(I2)
            XS2 = XREAL(I1) + XREAL(I3)
            XS3 = XREAL(I1) - XREAL(I3)
            YS2 = XIMAG(I1) + XIMAG(I3)
            YS3 = XIMAG(I1) - XIMAG(I3)

            XREAL(I0) = XS0 + XS2
            XIMAG(I0) = YS0 + YS2

            X1 = XS1 + YS3
            Y1 = YS1 - XS3
            X2 = XS0 - XS2
            Y2 = YS0 - YS2
            X3 = XS1 - YS3
            Y3 = YS1 + XS3

            IF(LITLA.GT.1) THEN
               GOTO 7
            ENDIF

            XREAL(I2) = X1
            XIMAG(I2) = Y1
            XREAL(I1) = X2
            XIMAG(I1) = Y2
            XREAL(I3) = X3
            XIMAG(I3) = Y3
            GOTO 8

! Now IF required - we multiply by twiddle factors:
 7          XREAL(I2) = X1*CW1 + Y1*SW1
            XIMAG(I2) = Y1*CW1 - X1*SW1
            XREAL(I1) = X2*CW2 + Y2*SW2
            XIMAG(I1) = Y2*CW2 - X2*SW2
            XREAL(I3) = X3*CW3 + Y3*SW3
            XIMAG(I3) = Y3*CW3 - X3*SW3
 8       CONTINUE
         IF(LITLA.EQ.IFACA) THEN
            GOTO 10
         ENDIF

! Calculate a new set of twiddle factors:
         Z = CW1*BCOS - SW1*BSIN + CW1
         SW1 = BCOS*SW1 + BSIN*CW1 + SW1
         TEMPR = 1.5 - 0.5*(Z*Z + SW1*SW1)
         CW1 = Z*TEMPR
         SW1 = SW1*TEMPR         
         CW2 = CW1*CW1 - SW1*SW1
         SW2 = 2.0*CW1*SW1
         CW3 = CW1*CW2 - SW1*SW2
         SW3 = CW1*SW2 + CW2*SW1
 10   CONTINUE
      IF(IFACA.LE.1) THEN 
         GOTO 14
      ENDIF

! Set up tranform split for next stage:
      IFACA = IFACA/4
      IF(IFACA.GT.0) THEN 
         GOTO 5
      ENDIF

! This is the calculation of a radix two-stage:
      DO 13, K = 1,N,2
         TEMPR = XREAL(K) + XREAL(K + 1)
         XREAL(K + 1) = XREAL(K) - XREAL(K + 1)
         XREAL(K) = TEMPR
         TEMPR = XIMAG(K) + XIMAG(K + 1)
         XIMAG(K + 1) = XIMAG(K) - XIMAG(K + 1)
         XIMAG(K) = TEMPR
 13   CONTINUE
 14   IF(ITYPE.GT.0) THEN
         GOTO 17
      ENDIF

! For the inverse case, cojugate and scale the transform:
      Z = 1.0/ZFLOAT(N)
      DO 16, K = 1,N
         XIMAG(K) = -XIMAG(K)*Z
         XREAL(K) = XREAL(K)*Z
 16   CONTINUE

 17   return

      END
! ----------------------------------------------------------
!-END of subroutine FASTG.FOR.
! ----------------------------------------------------------


!+ FILE: SCRAM.FOR
! ==========================================================
! Discription: Subroutine for unscrambiling FFT data:
! ==========================================================
      SUBROUTINE SCRAM(XREAL,XIMAG,N,IPOW)

      INTEGER L(19),II,J1,J2,J3,J4,J5,J6,J7,J8,J9,J10,J11,J12
      INTEGER J13,J14,J15,J16,J17,J18,J19,J20,ITOP,I
      REAL*8 XREAL(*),XIMAG(*),TEMPR

      EQUIVALENCE (L1,L(1)),(L2,L(2)),(L3,L(3)),(L4,L(4))
      EQUIVALENCE (L5,L(5)),(L6,L(6)),(L7,L(7)),(L8,L(8))
      EQUIVALENCE (L9,L(9)),(L10,L(10)),(L11,L(11)),(L12,L(12))
      EQUIVALENCE (L13,L(13)),(L14,L(14)),(L15,L(15)),(L16,L(16))
      EQUIVALENCE (L17,L(17)),(L18,L(18)),(L19,L(19))

      II = 1
      ITOP = 2**(IPOW - 1)
      I = 20 - IPOW
      DO 5, K = 1,I
         L(K) = II
 5    CONTINUE
      L0 = II 
      I = I + 1
      DO 6, K = I,19
         II = II*2
         L(K) = II
 6    CONTINUE
      II = 0
      DO 9, J1 = 1,L1,L0
        DO 9, J2 = J1,L2,L1
          DO 9, J3 = J2,L3,L2
            DO 9, J4 = J3,L4,L3
              DO 9, J5 = J4,L5,L4
                DO 9, J6 = J5,L6,L5
                  DO 9, J7 = J6,L7,L6
                    DO 9, J8 = J7,L8,L7
                      DO 9, J9 = J8,L9,L8
                        DO 9, J10 = J9,L10,L9
                          DO 9, J11 = J10,L11,L10
                            DO 9, J12 = J11,L12,L11
                              DO 9, J13 = J12,L13,L12
                                DO 9, J14 = J13,L14,L13
                                  DO 9, J15 = J14,L15,L14
                                    DO 9, J16 = J15,L16,L15
                                      DO 9, J17 = J16,L17,L16
                                        DO 9, J18 = J17,L18,L17
                                          DO 9, J19 = J18,L19,L18
                                             J20 = J19
                                             DO 9, I = 1,2
                                                II = II +1
                                                IF(II.GE.J20) THEN
                                                   GOTO 8
                                                ENDIF
! J20 is the bit reverse of II!
! Pairwise exchange:
                                                TEMPR = XREAL(II)
                                                XREAL(II) = XREAL(J20)
                                                XREAL(J20) = TEMPR
                                                TEMPR = XIMAG(II)
                                                XIMAG(II) = XIMAG(J20)
                                                XIMAG(J20) = TEMPR
 8                                              J20 = J20 + ITOP
 9    CONTINUE

      return

      END
! -------------------------------------------------------------------
!-END:
! -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Going through this and understanding it will take time! I wrote this using a CalTech paper I found years ago, I cannot recall the reference I am afraid. Good luck.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think OP wants to understand FFT, by first understanding DFT. I'm not sure dumping some old FORTRAN code will help him.

Comment: To _understand_ these subject areas, requires a maths book, time and a pen and paper. First fourier transforms in general, then the DFT, then the FFT algorithm etc. The implementation of a FFT is tough and I just thought that a complete code listing that is clearly commented would have helped _me_ way back when I was asked to produce a Wavelet code. I hear what you are saying but in doing this I have the best intentions, and am only trying to help the OP. I suppose he can take it or leave it... :]

Answer (score 2):

Your code works.
I would give more digits for PI ( 3.1415926535898 ).
Also, you have to devide the output of the DFT summation by S, the DFT size.

Since the input series in your test is constant, the DFT output should have only one non-zero coefficient.
And indeed all the output coefficients are very small relative to the first one.

But for a large input length, this is not an efficient way of implementing the DFT.
If timing is a concern, look into the [Fast Fourrier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) for faster methods to calculate the DFT.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks right to me. I'm not sure what you were expecting for output but, given that your input is a constant value, the DFT of a constant is a DC term in bin 0 and zeroes in the remaining bins (or a close equivalent, which you have).

You might try testing you code with a longer sequence containing some type of waveform like a sine wave or a square wave. In general, however, you should consider using something like fftw in production code. Its been wrung out and highly optimized by many people for a long time. FFTs are optimized DFTs for special cases (e.g., lengths that are powers of 2).

Answer (score 0):

MoonKnight has already provided a *radix-4 Decimation In Frequency* Cooley-Tukey scheme in Fortran. I'm below providing a *radix-2 Decimation In Frequency* Cooley-Tukey scheme in Matlab.

The code is an iterative one and considers the scheme in the following figure:

[image]

A recursive approach is also possible.

As you will see, the implementation calculates also the number of performed multiplications and additions and compares it with the theoretical calculations reported in [How many FLOPS for FFT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40036629/how-many-flops-for-fft/42261160#42261160).

The code is obviously much slower than the highly optimized FFTW exploited by Matlab.

Note also that the twiddle factors `omegaa^((2^(p - 1) * n))` can be calculated off-line and then restored from a lookup table, but this point is skipped in the code below.

For a Matlab implementation of an iterative *radix-2 Decimation In Time* Cooley-Tukey scheme, please see [Implementing a Fast Fourier Transform for Option Pricing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465079/implementing-a-fast-fourier-transform-for-option-pricing/42292490#42292490).

```
% --- Radix-2 Decimation In Frequency - Iterative approach

clear all
close all
clc

N = 32;

x = randn(1, N);
xoriginal = x;
xhat = zeros(1, N);

numStages = log2(N);

omegaa = exp(-1i * 2 * pi / N);

mulCount = 0;
sumCount = 0;
tic
M = N / 2;
for p = 1 : numStages;
    for index = 0 : (N / (2^(p - 1))) : (N - 1);
        for n = 0 : M - 1;        
            a = x(n + index + 1) + x(n + index + M + 1);
            b = (x(n + index + 1) - x(n + index + M + 1)) .* omegaa^((2^(p - 1) * n));
            x(n + 1 + index) = a;
            x(n + M + 1 + index) = b;
            mulCount = mulCount + 4;
            sumCount = sumCount + 6;
        end;
    end;
    M = M / 2;
end
xhat = bitrevorder(x);
timeCooleyTukey = toc;

tic
xhatcheck = fft(xoriginal);
timeFFTW = toc;

rms = 100 * sqrt(sum(sum(abs(xhat - xhatcheck).^2)) / sum(sum(abs(xhat).^2)));

fprintf('Time Cooley-Tukey = %f; \t Time FFTW = %f\n\n', timeCooleyTukey, timeFFTW);
fprintf('Theoretical multiplications count \t = %i; \t Actual multiplications count \t = %i\n', ...
         2 * N * log2(N), mulCount);
fprintf('Theoretical additions count \t\t = %i; \t Actual additions count \t\t = %i\n\n', ...
         3 * N * log2(N), sumCount);
fprintf('Root mean square with FFTW implementation = %.10e\n', rms);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct to obtain the DFT.

The function you are testing is `(sin ((double) i / points * frequency * 2)` which corresponds to a synoid of amplitude 1, frequency 1 and sampling frequency Fs = number of points taken.

Operating with the obtained data we have:

[image]

As you can see, the DFT coefficients are symmetric with respect to the position coefficient N / 2, so only the first N / 2 provide information. The amplitude obtained by means of the module of the real and imaginary part must be divided by N and multiplied by 2 to reconstruct it. The frequencies of the coefficients will be multiples of Fs / N by the coefficient number.

If we introduce two sinusoids, one of frequency 2 and amplitude 1.3 and another of frequency 3 and amplitude 1.7.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    numbers.push_back(1.3 *sin((double)i / 16 * frequency1 * 2 * PI)+ 1.7 *
        sin((double)i / 16 * frequency2 * 2 * PI));
}
```

The obtained data are:

[image]

Good luck.

Comment: Please inline the images so that they can be oberserved without leaving your answer.