# Understanding the radix-2 FFT recursive algorithm

Tags: fft, rad, dft

I'm currently studying DFT and FFT and we were given this simple question:
*se the recursive FFT to compute the DFT of this polynomial of third degree:
`-1 + 4x + 3x^2`*.

So, I'm considering this algorithm:
[image]

How does this recursion work? Is the `for` loop positioned at the end of all the recursion calls? Or every time `y` goes back to `y^0` and `y^1`? Can someone guide me? Of course, not all the steps, just some examples? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26355569/2521214 go to the fast agoritms bullet there and read also both two links in that sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive implementation of the *radix-2 Decimation In Frequency* algorithm can be understood using the following two figures. The first one refers to *pushing the stack* phase, while the second one illustrates the *popping the stack* phase.

[image]

[image]

In particular, the two figures illustrate the following Matlab implementation:

```
% --- Radix-2 Decimation In Frequency - Iterative approach

function y = radix2_DIF_Recursive(x)

global sumCount mulCount

N = length(x);
phasor = exp(-2 * pi * 1i / N) .^ (0 : N / 2 - 1);

if N == 1
    y = x;
else
    y_top       = radix2_DIF_Recursive(x(1: 2 : (N - 1)));
    y_bottom    = radix2_DIF_Recursive(x(2 : 2 : N));
    z           = phasor .* y_bottom;
    y           = [y_top + z, y_top - z];
    sumCount    = sumCount + 6 * (N / 2);
    mulCount    = mulCount + 4 * (N / 2);
end
```

Use the following main script to test it:

```
% --- Radix-2 Decimation In Frequency - Iterative approach

clear all
close all
clc

global sumCount mulCount

N = 32;

x = randn(1, N);

sumCount = 0;
mulCount = 0;

tic
xhat = radix2_DIF_Recursive(x);
timeCooleyTukey = toc;

tic
xhatcheck = fft(x);
timeFFTW = toc;

rms = 100 * sqrt(sum(sum(abs(xhat - xhatcheck).^2)) / sum(sum(abs(xhat).^2)));

fprintf('Time Cooley-Tukey = %f; \t Time FFTW = %f\n\n', timeCooleyTukey, timeFFTW);
fprintf('Theoretical multiplications count \t = %i; \t Actual multiplications count \t = %i\n', ...
         2 * N * log2(N), mulCount);
fprintf('Theoretical additions count \t\t = %i; \t Actual additions count \t\t = %i\n\n', ...
         3 * N * log2(N), sumCount);
fprintf('Root mean square with FFTW implementation = %.10e\n', rms);
```

The above recursive implementation is the counterpart of the iterative implementation of the *radix-2 Decimation In Frequency* at [Implementation of the Discrete Fourier Transform - FFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251453/implementation-of-the-discrete-fourier-transform-fft/42312565#42312565). Please, note that the present recursive one does not require any reverse bit ordering, neither of the input nor of the output sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, Recursive-FFT is working its way backwards through *a*, starting at (a0,a1,a2,...an).

At each subsequent recursive call to Recursive-FFT a subset of *a* is used, thus *a* in each newly called Recursive-FFT becomes ever smaller until its length as assigned to *n* is 1, at which point the last call to Recursive-FFT returns to the previous one.

It is not until Recursive-FFT has returned, when *n* = 1, to its caller, that the last part of the routine, the for-loop, is executed, at which point *y* is returned to either the previous Recursive-FFT, or the original caller (code that is not Recursive-FFT) when no more calls from Recursive-FFT exist on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Form the vector a = [-1, 4, 3, 0], which has a length of n=2=2^2.

Then (using a piece of paper) go through the steps of the algorithm: splitting the sequence into even/odd vectors etc. Have fun (or choose another subject for your studies).

By the way: the polynomial is only second degree, not third as you mention!?!

Comment: well, its 2 but we need it to be 3 to use FFT